# DataExplorer, customize univariate distribution

Tags: r, grouping, density-plot, exploratory-data-analysis, r-data-explorer

I am trying to use DataExplorer to help with quick EDA. I like how it shows univariate distributions. Here is a reproducible example.

```
A <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 200))
A<- factor(A)
B <- c(x=rnorm(1000))
C <- c(x= rnorm(1000, mean = 100, sd=2))
D <- c(x= rnorm(1000, 2, 2))
df<- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
df %>%
  create_report(
    output_file = "trial",
    y= "A", #to get barplots, QQ plots and scatterplots by grouping variable "A"
    report_title = "trial_EDA",
    config = configure_report(
      add_plot_density = TRUE  #To add density plots to report
    )
  )
```

I want to visualize density by grouping variable, "A", as shown in the picture attached.[image]

But I don't know how to use plot density args properly to do this. Also, please suggest other packages to easily navigate through large datasets as a preliminary analysis. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified which variable the `B`, `C` or `D` density graph should apply to.
If there is only one, e.g. `B` then do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

A <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 200))
A<- factor(A)
B <- c(x=rnorm(1000))
C <- c(x= rnorm(1000, mean = 100, sd=2))
D <- c(x= rnorm(1000, 2, 2))
df<- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

df %>% mutate(A = A %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(B, fill=A)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

You can also do it separately for each of the variables on one plot.

```
pB = df %>% mutate(A = A %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(B, fill=A)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.2)
pC = df %>% mutate(A = A %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(C, fill=A)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.2)

pD = df %>% mutate(A = A %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(D, fill=A)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.2)

ggarrange(pB, pC, pD, 
          labels = c("B", "C", "D"))
```

[image]

And if you don't like the fillings, you can do it like this

```
df %>% mutate(A = A %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(B, color=A)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

**Update 1**

It is possible to create charts for any number of columns. I will show it to you in the example below.
First, we'll do it in a very simple, even trivial way.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  A = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 200) %>% factor(),
  B = rnorm(1000),
  C = rnorm(1000, mean = 100, sd=2),
  D = rnorm(1000, 2, 2)
)

fPlot = function(x, group) tibble(x=x, group=group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, color=group)) +
    geom_density()

df %>% select_at(vars(B:D)) %>% 
    map(~fPlot(., df$A))
```

As you can see, we created three plots for variables `B`, `C` and `D`.

The second way is a bit more difficult to understand. But it will give you some extra bonuses.

```
fPlot2 = function(df, group) df$data[[1]] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, color=A)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle(group)

df %>% pivot_longer(B:D, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  group_map(fPlot2)
```

Note that your `tibble` after `df %>% pivot_longer(B:D, names_to = "var", values_to = "val")` looks like this.

```
# A tibble: 3,000 x 3
   A     var        val
   <fct> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 1     B       1.06  
 2 1     C     100.    
 3 1     D       3.54  
 4 2     B      -0.652 
 5 2     C     100.    
 6 2     D       1.12  
 7 3     B       0.652 
 8 3     C      97.3   
 9 3     D       3.57  
10 4     B      -0.0972
# ... with 2,990 more rows
```

After doing `df %>% pivot_longer(B:D, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>% group_by(var) %>% nest()` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   var [3]
  var   data                
  <chr> <list>              
1 B     <tibble [1,000 x 2]>
2 C     <tibble [1,000 x 2]>
3 D     <tibble [1,000 x 2]>
```

As you can see the data has been collapsed into three internal `tibble` in the variable `data`.
This approach will allow you to easily calculate all statistics for each column separately. Look at this.

```
fStat = function(df) df$data[[1]] %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    min = min(val),
    mean = mean(val),
    max = max(val),
    median = median(val),
    sd = sd(val),
    sw.stat = stats::shapiro.test(val)$statistic,
    sw.p = stats::shapiro.test(val)$p.value,
  )

df %>% pivot_longer(B:D, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  group_modify(~fStat(.x))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 10
# Groups:   var [3]
   var   A         n   min      mean    max     median    sd sw.stat  sw.p
   <chr> <fct> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 B     1       200 -2.14   0.139     3.16   0.153    0.960   0.994 0.561
 2 B     2       200 -2.00   0.0185    2.61   0.0162   0.923   0.992 0.373
 3 B     3       200 -3.15   0.0245    2.42   0.0718   1.02    0.992 0.347
 4 B     4       200 -2.75   0.00112   2.73  -0.00691  1.02    0.993 0.496
 5 B     5       200 -3.32  -0.00758   3.23  -0.000105 0.993   0.991 0.250
 6 C     1       200 94.6   99.8     104.    99.8      1.97    0.992 0.365
 7 C     2       200 94.8  100.      104.   100.       1.85    0.991 0.290
 8 C     3       200 94.5  100.      106.   100.       1.94    0.996 0.877
 9 C     4       200 94.4   99.9     107.    99.9      1.97    0.993 0.463
10 C     5       200 94.3   99.8     106.    99.8      2.07    0.996 0.887
11 D     1       200 -4.89   1.81      8.11   1.90     2.09    0.995 0.750
12 D     2       200 -5.42   2.15      7.57   2.18     2.14    0.995 0.726
13 D     3       200 -4.38   2.09      7.10   2.02     1.97    0.989 0.111
14 D     4       200 -4.73   2.13      8.98   1.93     1.99    0.989 0.138
15 D     5       200 -2.19   2.24      7.79   2.25     1.87    0.996 0.867
```

Czy to nie fajne?

Comment: Density graph should apply to all numerical variables. I have a huge data set unlike the one in the example. It is difficult to go through these initial steps of checking the data manually! The DataExplorer package figures out all the numerical variables in the data set and gives me this plot. Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to apply density distribution with grouping variable within DataExplorer arguments!

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all numerical variable columns with your code?

Comment: Yes, there is such a possibility. I can show you how to do it. However, specify which graph is more suitable for you with or without filling. Also specify if you want to have each variable (column) on a separate plot or if you prefer to collect everything on one as in my other solution.

Comment: Hello Nidhi. If my answer was helpful, remember that on Stack Overflow you can say thank you by marking the accepted answer.